# swift element is empty

Tags: swift, core-data, nsset

I am trying to get the first or current exercise from my core data but swift keeps telling me that the element is empty. When i run the app and set the break points the debugger shows that the element is empty but no errors. here are the functions i am using to get the element data.

```
func currentWorkout() -> Workout? {
    let client = currentClient()
    return (appointment?.workouts as? Set<Workout>)?.first(where: { $0.client == client })
}

private func currentCard() -> Card? {
    return currentWorkout()?.card
}

private func currentClientPlannedExercises() -> [ExerciseInfo] {
    if let currentCard = currentCard(), let template = currentCard.template, let exerciseSets = template.exerciseSets?.array as? [ExerciseSet] {
        let numCardsWithThis = (template.cardsWithThisTemplate as? Set<Card>)?.filter { $0.client != currentClient() }.count ?? 0
        let exercsiseSetNumber = numCardsWithThis % exerciseSets.count
        if let result = exerciseSets[exercsiseSetNumber].exercises?.array as? [ExerciseInfo] {
            return result
        }
    }
    return [ExerciseInfo]()
}

private func currentExercise() -> Exercise? {
    // we can't have an exercise without a selection
    guard let selectedExercise = currentExerciseInfo(), let currentCard = currentCard() else{
        return nil
    }
    // get the first exercise on the current card that has the same exercise info as the one selected
    if let exercises = currentWorkout()?.exercises as? Set<Exercise>{
        return exercises.first(where: { $0.exerciseInfo == selectedExercise })
    }
    let exercise = Exercise(context: context)
    exercise.workout = currentWorkout()
    exercise.exerciseInfo = selectedExercise
    //TODO: Set Seat
    return exercise
}
private func currentExerciseInfo() -> ExerciseInfo? {
    guard let selectedRow = exercisesTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else {
        return nil
    }
    return currentClientPlannedExercises()[selectedRow.row]
}
```

Comment: Facing issue in fetching the data from core data right.?

Comment: its either that or they aren't saving to core data

Comment: Added the Answer to fetch the data from core data My Way. Hope it helps, if the problem is in adding lemme know i will update the Code for you.

Comment: What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the Issue is fetching then You can use this Code:

**For Fetching the data from `Core Data`**

```
    var tasks: [Task] = [] //Your Entity Name in Bracket

    func getData() {
  do {
    tasks = try context.fetch(Task.fetchRequest()) //Instead of Task your Entity Name
    } catch {
      print("Fetching Failed")
    }
  }
```

And use it like:

```
for data in tasks{
        print(data.name) // All the Attributes name after data.attributename
        print(data.address)
    }
```

**If it is in tableView:**

```
let data = tasks[indexPath.row]
 print(data.name)
```

You will get the data if it is there.

### Edit to Check if Data entered or not

Print the Path like this:

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
print(paths[0])
```

Go to sqlite file and open and check if there is Data or not inside that.

### Edit If you are facing the issue in Adding Data to Core Data

Simple code to add Data

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
let task = Task(context: context) //Entity Name here instead of Task
task.name = taskTextField.text! // Attribute name here after task.attributename

// Save the data to coredata
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
```

Hope this help.

Comment: So while the app is running i hovered over element and elements in the function currentExercise and they are coming up with no value

Comment: So i guess the value is not being entered

Comment: but i am seeing it change in the textFieldDidBeginEditing function

Comment: Have you tried my function for fetching the Data from Core data.? Edited the answer to check the Data directly in DB

Comment: I looked at the data and nothing is saving to it. The function you gave me never runs while running the app

Comment: @MattBrown Have edited the answer to save the data my Way, I almost use this in every project and it work like charm. Try saving using this and fetching using my way. If it works for you do not forget to accept my answer . cheers!

Comment: I found the issue was in the currentExercise function it wasn't calling the first exercise until the it had an exercise. I fixed by rewriting line 
if let exercises = currentWorkout()?.exercises as? Set<Exercise>, let firstExercise = exercises.first(where: { $0.exerciseInfo == selectedExercise }) {
            return firstExercise

Comment: Any ways if it helped you, then you can approve my answer for that. Had helped you in detecting the steps

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue was in the currentExercise function it wasn't calling the first exercise until the it had an exercise. I fixed by rewriting the function

```
private func currentExercise() -> Exercise? {
    // we can't have an exercise without a selection
    guard let selectedExercise = currentExerciseInfo() else{
        return nil
    }
    // get the first exercise on the current card that has the same exercise info as the one selected
    if let exercises = currentWorkout()?.exercises as? Set<Exercise>, let firstExercise = exercises.first(where: { $0.exerciseInfo == selectedExercise }) {
        return firstExercise
    }
    let exercise = Exercise(context: context)
    exercise.workout = currentWorkout()
    exercise.exerciseInfo = selectedExercise
    //TODO: Set Seat
    return exercise
}
```